# Rust macro_rules nested repetition

Tags: rust, macros, repeat

In a macro_rules! transcriber, nested repetitions are not handled properly. This works fine:

```
macro_rules! demo_macro {
    ($op:tt; $($arg:tt),*) {
        ($($op * $arg),*)
    }
}

fn main() {
    println!("{?:}", demo_macro!(2; 1,2,3));
}
```

and outputs `(2, 4, 6)`, but this does not compile:

```
macro_rules! demo_macro {
    ([$($op:tt)*] $($arg:tt),*) {
        ($($($op)* $arg),*)
    }
}

fn main() {
    println!("{?:}", demo_macro!([2*] 1,2,3));
}
```

and results in this error message:

```
error: meta-variable `op` repeats 2 times, but `arg` repeats 3 times
 --> src/main.rs:3:11
  |
3 |         ($($($op)* $arg),*)
  |           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

If I change `1,2,3` to `1,2` so the repetition counts match up, I get this error message:

```
error: attempted to repeat an expression containing no syntax variables matched as repeating at this depth
 --> src/main.rs:3:13
  |
3 |         ($($($op)* $arg),*)
  |             ^^^^^
```

Any idea how to make `demo_macro!([2*] 1,2,3)` result in `(2, 4, 6)`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yay, this works!

```
macro_rules! unbracket {
    (_ [$($tt1:tt)*]) => { $($tt1)* };
    (() [$($tt1:tt)*]) => { ($($tt1)*) };
    ([] [$($tt1:tt)*]) => { [$($tt1)*] };
    ({} [$($tt1:tt)*]) => { {$($tt1)*} };
    ($tt0:tt [$($tt1:tt)*] @unbracket ($($tt2:tt)*) $($tt3:tt)*) => { unbracket!{ $tt0 [$($tt1)* $($tt2)*] $($tt3)*} };
    ($tt0:tt [$($tt1:tt)*] @unbracket [$($tt2:tt)*] $($tt3:tt)*) => { unbracket!{ $tt0 [$($tt1)* $($tt2)*] $($tt3)*} };
    ($tt0:tt [$($tt1:tt)*] @unbracket {$($tt2:tt)*} $($tt3:tt)*) => { unbracket!{ $tt0 [$($tt1)* $($tt2)*] $($tt3)*} };
    ($tt0:tt [$($tt1:tt)*] $tt2:tt $($tt3:tt)*) => { unbracket!{$tt0 [$($tt1)* $tt2] $($tt3)*} };
}

macro_rules! demo_macro {
    ($op:tt $($arg:tt),*) => {
        unbracket!(() [] $(@unbracket $op $arg),*)
    }
}

fn main() {
    println!("{:?}", demo_macro!([2*] 1,2,3));
}
```