# Repetition inside an optional pattern

Tags: rust, macros

I'm trying to generate a struct optionally, based on the presence of an optional pattern `$( … )?`:

```rust
macro_rules! accounts_struct {
    (
        $( #[seeds: struct $StructSeedsName:ident] )?
        struct $StructAccountsName:ident {
            $(
                pub $account:ident,
            )*
        }
    ) => {
        pub struct $StructAccountsName {
            $(
                pub $account: String,
            )*
        }
        
        $(
            pub struct $StructSeedsName {
                $(
                    pub $account: u8,
                )*
            }
        )?
    }
}

accounts_struct! {
    #[seeds: struct Seeds]
    struct Accounts {
        pub foo,
        pub bar,
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=c5bf02e17fdfafab746013e69a1e71ad).

Unfortunately, it looks like I'm not allowed to do that:

```
error: meta-variable `StructSeedsName` repeats 1 time, but `account` repeats 2 times
  --> src/lib.rs:16:10
   |
16 |           $(
   |  __________^
17 | |             pub struct $StructSeedsName {
18 | |                 $(
19 | |                     pub $account: u8,
20 | |                 )*
21 | |             }
22 | |         )?
   | |_________^
```

What can I use as a workaround?

Comment: This question is a dup of mine, but the answer don't really match my problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61045284/rust-macro-rules-nested-repetition

Comment: If I understand the issue, I must nest the repetition in the expansion part exactly as in the declaration part.

Answer (score 1):

As a last resort, you can repeat yourself like so, to cover a case when the optional section is present and when it's not

```rust
macro_rules! accounts_struct {
    (
        #[seeds: struct $StructSeedsName:ident]
        struct $StructAccountsName:ident {
            $(
                pub $account:ident,
            )*
        }
    ) => {
        pub struct $StructAccountsName {
            $(
                pub $account: String,
            )*
        }
        
        
        pub struct $StructSeedsName {
            $(
                pub $account: String,
            )*    
        }
    };
    (
        struct $StructAccountsName:ident {
            $(
                pub $account:ident,
            )*
        }
    ) => {
        pub struct $StructAccountsName {
            $(
                pub $account: String,
            )*
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Yes, I think it's what I'll do. In my real use case, there is a several hundreds lines generated, so I cannot repeat all the code, but I can add an intermediate step with an internal representation: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=8ab49d41fa0eee660ffe51db1dd397ec